# Otp not receiving on the mobile using Sms Api

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am using Mysmsmantra SMS API for OTP validation on registration time. When I click on send OTP it's not working properly. I am new for API integration, can nyone gives me suggestions on how it will work?

I already tried many different things according to me, but its not sending to the mobile number.

```
    <label>Mobile</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile">
     <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary" name="otp">send otp 
     </button>
     <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['otp'])) {
        $otp=rand(0000,9999);
         $username='JNY';
         $password= 360806208;
          $sender_name='jouRNEY';
          $sendTo = $_POST['mobile'];
          $sendMsg ="Your Otp is:".$otp;
         $url = 'http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp? 
username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&sendername=' .$sender_name.'&mobileno=' . $sendTo . '&message=' . $sendMsg;
          $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
        echo $curl_scraped_page;
           }
            ?>
```

Its nothing sending, I need to receive an OTP on my mobile.

Comment: anyone give me suggestions